# how to merge multiple rows into 1 row in a single table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Table name called NOTES,
columns NAMES = ID,Date,code,text

```
ID   DATE           CODE     TEXT
1    7/24/2013       CD1     HELLO

1    7/24/2013       CD1     STACK OVER FLOW

2    1/24/2000       CD2     PLEASE HELP ME 

2    1/24/2000       CD2     THANK YOU 

2    1/24/2000       CD2     VERY MUCH
```

my Requirement: oracle SQL LOGIC

```
ID   DATE           CODE     TEXT

1    7/24/2013       CD1     HELLO, STACK OVER FLOW

2    1/24/2000       CD2     PLEASE HELP ME, THANK YOU, VERY MUCH
```

Comment: show people what you have tried so far, they will be more willing to help that way.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php) for several options.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT 
ID,
DATE,
CODE,
LISTAGG(TEXT, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CODE)
FROM NAMES
GROUP BY ID, DATE, CODE
```